# How to publish Asp.Net core MVC web application on Godaddy's shared web hosting

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, hosting, asp.net-core-2.1

I have developed an asp.net core 2.1 web application with entity framework core. Now I would like to host the application on my Godaddy's shared web hosting account. I am trying this with FTP but it is not working. Does anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error message that you see? The following is steps to publish your application:

1. Please open your project with Visual Studio tool
2. On the Solution Explorer windows (which is normally located on the top right hand corner of the VS tool), right click your project and select Publish
3. Please kindly publish it to a local folder, such as C:\Project
4. Please just upload whatever files/folders you see on C:\Project to the server via FTP and your site will work fine.

**Important NOTE:**

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 or later version, the publishing step may look a bit different.

1. Please open your website project with Visual Studio 2015. They may have been a pre-set .NET version on your project.
2. Then, please go to the Solution Explorer, Right Click the project and select "Publish Web App" website. Please select "FTP" as the deployment method
3. Please hit Publish

You can also read this documentation http://windows2008hosting.asphostportal.com/post/Cheap-ASPNET-MVC-3-Hosting-ASPHostPortal-How-to-Deploy-an-ASPNET-MVC-3-App-to-Web-Hosting-with-5cbin-Deployment.aspx. I use this tutorial to deploy my previous MVC. :)

Comment: Didn't work - this just provides publish steps - doesnt help with asp CORE

Comment: @MarkSpender -  HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure - I've consulted godaddy support - I'm told everything is installed and configured properly - my app works everywhere else - moving to Azure

Comment: @OverMars It seems that Godaddy doesn't support .net core, for error above, you can read https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

From what I found on GoDaddy forums, do correct me if I'm wrong, GoDaddy doesn't support .NET Core on shared hosting yet. I believe Plesk Onyx will support this (mine is still on Odin) and after a conversation with GoDaddy customer service, they don't have a date for the upgrade yet.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. but i guess there is some trick to run it on godaddy's shared hosting.